# Low framerate when running Piston example

Tags: performance, rust, game-engine

I'm building a simple 2D game in Rust using Piston. I used examples from the Piston documentation and expanded it and it works quite well. However, I get pretty bad performance:

- Drawing only 2 squares gives me a framerate of about 30-40 FPS
- Drawing 5 000 squares gives me a framerate of about 5 FPS

This is on a Core i7 @ 2.2GHz running Windows 10. Rust version 1.8, Piston version 0.19.0.

Is this expected or have I made any mistakes in my code? Am I even measuring the FPS correctly?

```
extern crate piston_window;
extern crate piston;
extern crate rand;

use piston_window::*;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {

    const SIZE: [u32; 2] = [600,600];

    const GREEN: [f32; 4] = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0];


    const NUM: u32 = 1000; //change this to change number of polygons
    const SQUARESIZE: f64 = 10.0;


    // Create an Glutin window.
    let window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new("test",SIZE)
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let mut frames = 0;
    let mut passed = 0.0;

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    for e in window {

        if let Some(_) = e.render_args() {
            e.draw_2d(|c, g| {

                //clear the screen.
                clear(GREEN, g);

                for i in 0..NUM {

                    //setting up so that it looks pretty
                    let x = (i % SIZE[0]) as f64;
                    let y = (i % SIZE[1]) as f64;
                    let fill = (x / (SIZE[0] as f64)) as f32;
                    let color: [f32; 4] = [fill,1.0-fill,fill,fill];

                    let x = rng.gen_range::<f64>(0.0,SIZE[0] as f64);

                    //draw the square
                    let square = rectangle::square(0.0, 0.0, SQUARESIZE);
                    let transform = c.transform.trans(x-SQUARESIZE/2.0,y-SQUARESIZE/2.0);
                    rectangle(color, square, transform, g);

                }

                frames+=1;
            });
        }

        if let Some(u) = e.update_args() {

            passed += u.dt;

            if passed > 1.0 {

                let fps = (frames as f64) / passed;

                println!("FPS: {}",fps);

                frames = 0;
                passed = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: taskmgr tells me that it only uses about 17K memory, but one of my physical CPU cores maxes out when the FPS drops below about 20.

EDIT 2: Changed the code to a complete working example.

Comment: Are you building your code in release mode? `cargo build --release` or `cargo run --release`?

Comment: I was not (Rookie mistake), and it improved performance (Thanks!). But I still feel it should be faster - at 5K objects I get 27 FPS, at 10K objects I get 11 FPS.

Comment: What FPS do you expect at various numbers of polygons on screen?

Comment: Perhaps [fps_counter](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/fps_counter) can help make sure you are getting appropriate values?

Comment: The purpose of this question is partly to set my expectations before I delve into this project. If what I'm seeing is expected performance of piston, I can use that when I design my game. If, however, I've made a mistake in my design that greatly affects performance, I want to know about it before I build any further. But my experience from other game engines says that 11FPS with 10K polygons is a bit low. I will test fps_counter, but when I look at it I can see that it starts to lag significantly below 15 FPS. So my homegrown counter is probably not way off.

Comment: Could you give a complete example? You can't debug performance problems without being able to measure performance.

Comment: Updated the question with a complete example. I have some code that makes the squares colored and moving (so that you can se when it starts to lag) but even when drawing all the squares in the same place with a static color you get the same framerate.

Comment: I haven't used Piston, but I feel like maybe you shouldn't be creating a brand new square every frame?